# Android Studio proxy settings build error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

---

Whenever I try to build my app in Android Studio I get the following error:

`Error:169.254/16|*.169.254/16. Will ignore proxy settings for these hosts.`

I get the error 5 times. Its nothing specific to my project because I get the error when I create a new project from scratch. Moreover, the problem persists even after I **removed and reinstalled** Android Studio.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I've never ran into this issue but what happens if you go to Preferences --> HTTP Proxy? Is "No Proxy" selected? Also, what version of Android Studio are you running?

Comment: says no proxy. running latest version. actually fixed the issue, but I'm still not sure why it happened. i'll post an answer later today

Comment: Did you end up solving this? I have this problem happening right now and can't get around it.

Comment: unfortunately, i can't remember, but I think it had something to do with my DNS settings.

Answer (score 2):

Had same issue, in Android studio Preference >> Http Proxy >> selected Auto-Detect proxy settings

Comment: Works for me, Thanks Alot!