# Android Studio: Gradle build Error:169.254/16|*.169.254/16. Will ignore proxy settings for these hosts

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I installed Android Studio a few weeks ago and I was able to create new projects and they built fine and I had them running. All of a sudden when I create a new project, gradle doesn't build because I get 6 of these errors:

Error:169.254/16|*.169.254/16. Will ignore proxy settings for these hosts.

That's all it says. I tried finding information online and even here but I have found nothing useful on this error. Someone mentioned it had something to do with their DNS settings but nothing on how to fix it. I am still able to run and build my old projects. I just can't build any new ones.

I really appreciate help on this as I can't move forward on my project. Thank you

Comment: Frustratingly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049944/android-studio-proxy-settings-build-error

Comment: I know. I saw that post but it didn't have an answer so I was hoping maybe someone knows how to answer it now. I can delete my question if this breaks stack overflow rules. Sorry this is my second time posting here. Like I said, I can't figure out this problem and don't know what else to do

Comment: Man, I feel your pain.  Just know there are people out here looking to help...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same errors in my project. I'm under Mac OSX. I don't know other platforms. I fixed it doing the following:

1. Close Android Studio.
2. Go to System Preference > Network
3. Select your active connection and go to Advanced... settings.
4. Select the Proxies tab.
5. Delete everything from "Bypass Proxy Settings for These Hosts and Domains".
6. Restart computer.

Hope I helped you or anyone else with the same problem. This was a hard one to figure out.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to still work on the project with these errors but I'm relieved to finally get rid of them. Thanks!

Comment: I did but not solved this issue on the latest ```AndroidStudio 1.5.1```. This happens on a existing project. Making a new one it works instead.